# Can i create a git commit template passing the branch name?

Tags: git, templates, commit

Every day i wrote my commits like this:

```
git commit -m "[develop] - Fix some features"
```

I would like to know if is possible i create a custom git commit template with the branch name.

Something like this:

```
[<BRANCH_NAME>] - COMMIT MESSAGE
```

Comment: I always do something like `feat: messag` (and keep feature short), but sometimes the branch name isnt a great indicator for that (fix-bug-1234: foo the bar v. internal-feature: foo the bar with bug number later in message)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I need to send with the branch name because i use Github and Jira. Jira need's this reference to track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `prepare-commit-message` hook to modify the commit message if you like.  This hook allows you to edit the file containing the commit message, which is passed as the first argument.  See the `githooks(5)` manual page for more details.

As a note, it usually isn't a good idea to put the branch name into the commit summary, since (a) it takes valuable space up on the first line and (b) if you merge the changes into another branch later, nobody will care what branch they were on originally.  But if you still want to do that, the hook can do that for you.

Comment: I need to send with the branch name because i use Github and Jira. Jira need's this reference to track.